# Learning a point on the sphere using signs of dot products

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, spherical-geometry, geometric-probability

An unknown point $x$ is fixed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we iterate as follows: at each step, specify a unit vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and record $\mathrm{sign}(x\cdot v).$

The goal is to design a strategy for specifying $x$ to within the smallest ball with the fewest possible steps.

With the first step you learn which of two hemispheres $x$ is in. The next step can get you to within a quarter, the next $1/8,$ and so on. With each step you are capable of cutting in half the region $x$ can be in.

A natural strategy to get a well-localized region is to first fix an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and cycle through it, each step slicing the region along the corresponding basis element's direction.  After $\ell$ steps, $x$ will be known to within a simplex with area $\propto 2^{-\ell}$. But what is the size of the ball for this strategy? Is there a better strategy?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-218/S0025-5718-97-00809-0/S0025-5718-97-00809-0.pdf

Comment: I suspect that the paper you link to answers your question, When the number of bisections is large the simplex is nearly flat.